# Merge objects updating duplicate keys (case-insensitively)

Tags: javascript, configuration

I'm using a javascript module that has a configuration object. One is already set with defaults and the user can pass in values to overwrite these set values. I am using Object.assign to merge the two objects.

Here is an example:

```
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // <-- default config
const source = { B: 4, c: 5 }; // <-- User input config 

Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target); //{a: 1, b: 2, B: 4, c: 5}
```

In this example if the user accidentally types in an uppercase 'B' instead of a lowercase one then the config object adds another value to itself when what I really want is the lowercase 'b' to be updated.
I know that's the intended behavior of Object.assign but trying to make this easier for the user and be case insensitive.

Comment: So you need to create a method that loops over the keys and makes the uniform.

Comment: Or make the user do it right in the first place.

Comment: Do you have mixed-case field names, `firstEntry`, or some such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is a little different from the others.  It normalizes only the keys found in the initial object, leaving the others intact.  Something like this:

```js
insensitiveAssign ({a: 1, b: 2}, {B: 4, c: 5, D: 6}) //=> {a: 1, b: 4, c: 5, D: 6}
//                                                         ^     ^     ^     ^
//                                 unaltered --------------'     |     |     |
//                                 overwritten ------------------+     |     |
//                                 added ------------------------------+     |
//                                 added (note: key not modified) -----------+
```

That may or may not be of use to you, but it's an interesting approach to the problem.  It also does not modify either of your objects, creating an altered clone instead.

```js
const insensitiveAssign = (target, source) => {
  const keys = Object .keys (target) .reduce ((a, k) => ((a[k.toLowerCase()] = k), a), {})
  return Object .entries (source) .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => {
    const lowerK = k.toLowerCase()
    const key = lowerK in keys ? keys[lowerK] : k
    a[key] = v;
    return a
  }, Object.assign({}, target)) // start with a shallow copy
}

  
const target = {a: 1, b: 2};
const source = {B: 4, c: 5, D: 6}; 

console .log (
  'result:',
  insensitiveAssign (target, source),
)
console .log (
  'target:', 
  target,
)
console .log (
  'source:',
  source
)
```

### Update

A comment updated the question to ask how this might be applied to nested objects.  In actuality, I would probably try to write that from scratch, but I don't have time now and a (only slightly tested) modification of this seems like it would work:

```js
const insensitiveAssign = (target, source) => {
  // if-block added
  if (Object(target) !== target || (Object(source) !== source)) {
    return source
  }
  const keys = Object .keys (target) .reduce ((a, k) => ((a[k.toLowerCase()] = k), a), {})
  return Object .entries (source) .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => {
    const lowerK = k.toLowerCase()
    const key = lowerK in keys ? keys[lowerK] : k
    a[key] = insensitiveAssign(target[key], v); // this line updated
    return a
  }, Object.assign({}, target))
}

  
const target = {a: 1, b: 2, x: {w: 'a', y: {z: 42}}};
const source = {B: 4, c: 5, D: 6, x: {V: 'c', Y: {z: 101}}}; 

console .log (
  'result:',
  insensitiveAssign (target, source),
)
console .log (
  'target:', 
  target,
)
console .log (
  'source:',
  source
)
```

Comment: You answer is brilliant! What would I need to change if I had a nested object in the config? The values get updated but the capitalization does not persist. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to lowercase the object keys first, like done [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/162418)

```js
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // <-- default config
const source = { B: 4, c: 5 }; // <-- User input config 

const lowerSource = Object.keys(source).reduce((c, k) => (c[k.toLowerCase()] = source[k], c), {});

Object.assign(target, lowerSource);

console.log(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply remap `source` object lower-casing its keys with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then pass resulting key-value pairs as parameter to [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 },
      source = { B: 4, c: 5 },
      
      result = Object.assign(
        target, 
        ...Object
          .keys(source)
          .map(key => 
            ({[key.toLowerCase()]: source[key]}))
      )
      
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below code.

```
target = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // <-- default config
source = { B: 4, c: 5 }; // <-- User input config 

source = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source).toLowerCase())

Object.assign(target, source);
```

Comment: A dangerous solution as it would change the key *values* as well, which may or may not be ok. It would also suffer from the overhead of stringifying/re-parsing, although that's likely not a large concern.

Comment: Yes Dave, I wanted to show a different way. My mistake did not added negative part of it. One more disadvantage of using stringify is it will ignore the functions in a object.